# Zip all folders in current directory

Tags: shell-script, zip

Im new to shell scripting and I was wondering if there was a way to zip all subdirectories individually in the current directory doing something that seemed familiar to high level programers.
ie:

```
for folder in currentDir:
    zip(folder)
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
cd /some/directory || exit 1
for i in *; do
    test -d "$i" && zip -r "$i.zip" "$i"
done
```